# What exactly does NVPROF Power Profile measure?

Tags: profiling, gpu, nvidia, nvprof

I have used NVPROF to get the power profile of a Kepler Architecture NVIDIA GPUs. My question is what exactly are we seeing? If I understand correctly there is a 12V and 3.3V rail feeding the GPU and the GPU can draw power from the PCI Bus. Is the NVPROF power samples a sum of the three? Or something else?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the sum of all power consumed by the GPU from all of its power rails/sources.

It is intended to be a measurement comparable to what `nvidia-smi` would report, or comparable to what is available in [NVML](http://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/index.html) (upon which `nvidia-smi` is built.)

It should be comparable to [this NVML API call](http://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/group__nvmlDeviceQueries.html#group__nvmlDeviceQueries_1g7ef7dff0ff14238d08a19ad7fb23fc87).

Comment: Robert, thank you! Can you provide me with any NVIDIA documentation to cite this fact-- that it is the sum of the power from all sources. If I can ask, are you an NVIDIA employee? I was aware of the API link and I agree that I believe NVPROF Is using that power sampling API call under the hood. This is about the only documentation I can find for the internal power sensor.

Comment: Yes, I work for NVIDIA.  No,  I can't provide any documentation to cite this fact.  There may be documentation that supports it, I just can't put my finger on it.

Comment: The man page for `nvidia-smi` states:        *Power Draw     The  last  **measured  power draw for the entire board**, in watts.  Only available if power management is supported.  This   reading  is  accurate  to  within  +/-  5  watts. Requires Inforom PWR object version  3.0  or  higher  on Kepler device.* I realize this doesn't explicitly tie to nvprof.  However both represent a sampled sequence of measurements.  Current versions of nvidia-smi can sample the power on a sub-second basis, I believe.

Comment: Robert, as always thanks!

As a side note, yes, NVPROF samples power ~ 50 Hz in my experience (that may be architecture dependent)